# Write to same performance counter from multiple processes

Tags: c#, performancecounter

I'm using the newer [System.Diagnostics.PerformanceData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancedata.aspx) set of api's to write to my counters and would like to increment / decrement a single counter from multiple processes simultaneously.

I've tried tweaking the CounterSetInstanceType in various ways with no success:

If i use Multiple or MultipleAggregate i always see a single instance in perfmon, but there is really a separate counter for each process and they overwrite each other. The same behavior happens with a Single counterset type.

When i try a gloablAggregate counterset type performance monitor doesn't seem to read the values at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

As documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee781345%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

You need to specify how to aggregate the counters within the manifest file (by setting the aggregate attribute for each counter).

It would appear that not doing so will cause the counters to simply stay at 0 / undefined.

In the case of globalAggregate this works perfectly.

In the case of multipleAggregate this only has an impact on the _Total instance that is created for the counterset automatically (as a result of defining it as multipleAggregate). All other instances remain at the old behavior.

There also seems to be a 'MultipleInstanceAggregate' counter type however as far as i can tell it is unsupported by the manifest schema. (See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancedata.countersetinstancetype)